# Run Docker Network using Amazon ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I have a docker network that I'd like to run on AWS, preferably using the [Fargate Launch type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_GetStarted_Fargate.html).

Pushing images to the ECR (Elastic Container Registry) is not a problem, but I am not sure how to push a network. I have the following commands to run it locally on my machine:

```
docker pull zilutian/hadoop
docker pull zilutian/data-analytics
docker network create hadoop-net
docker run -d --net hadoop-net --name master --hostname master zilutian/data-analytics master
docker run -d --net hadoop-net --name slave01 --hostname slave01 zilutian/hadoop slave
docker run -d --net hadoop-net --name slave02 --hostname slave02 zilutian/hadoop slave
docker exec master benchmark
```

I'm not sure if I need to push the network or the master and slaves?

Answer (score 1):

The *only* thing you can push to ECR (or any other image registry) is the Docker images themselves; the contents of the `zilutian/data-analytics` and `zilutian/Hadoop` images you reference in the `docker run` command.  You can’t push a network, running containers, processes in a container, or anything else.

90% of this you can encapsulate in a Docker Compose YAML file, which is probably the easiest way to describe this set of images, run commands, and a private network.  You can check this file into source control; there is no way to push it to a Docker registry.  (Or alternatively you can just check in the file from the question as a shell script and run it.)

The one thing you can’t include in this is the `docker exec` command.  It’s unclear why you’d want to launch a benchmark out of a Hadoop master node; I would `docker run` a separate container that’s the benchmarking tool, or possibly run it outside of Docker directly from the host or somewhere else you can access the cluster.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, @David, when you say run the file as a shell script, do you mean just doing it on a single EC2 instance, like what I did on my local Linux machine? This benchmark is part of a Cloud performance benchmark suite and that is why I'd like to test the Fargate to evaluate its performance. If more details about the benchmark help, this is the link: https://github.com/parsa-epfl/cloudsuite/blob/master/docs/benchmarks/data-analytics.md  So, any suggestions on how to use it with the `docker exec` command?